# How to set Time To Live (device expiry) without using C# on Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I know [Improved Per Message Telemetry and device expiry for Notification Hubs article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hub-telemetry-expiry-update/) describes setting TTL programmatically, but this seems a bit of a roundabout method, especially when maintaining multiple environments.

Is there any way to perform this through the Azure portal?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no way to set the property through the portal, unfortunately.

One alternative to using C# would be to [create/update your hub through REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223269.aspx) by using `RegistrationTtl` property on [Notification​Hub​Description object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubdescription?view=azurenotificationhubs-1.0.7)

You can also [leave feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs) about it and if enough people upvote it, the product team will prioritize the feature.